# How find out programmatically from which category the test was started?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nunit

Some methods have few categories attributes. In test explorer I can run test grouped by categories. Some tests  need a different parameter which is related with that category attribute, so I'd like to know how to check  from which category the test was started? 
Thanks for any advice.

C#
test framerwork NUnit.
VS 2012.

```
[test,cat1,cat2,cat3]
public void someTest()
{
   from which category the test was started?
}
```

Comment: What kind of different parameter?

Comment: i followed stacktrace but i didnt find it.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of input and desired output for such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [TestCase](http://nunit.org/?p=testCase&r=2.5) attribute? It provides a way to pass input params and provide a proper category:

```
[TestCase(0, Category = "cat1")]
[TestCase(50, Category = "cat2")]
```